# Right join not selecting null

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am trying to join aggregate some metrics based on dates. Problem is that only the dates with matching associations get's selected. I want the full range of dates, with 0 for no matching associations.

I am trying with this

```
SELECT f2."day", coalesce(count(c0."id"), 0) 
FROM "conversations" AS c0 
LEFT OUTER JOIN "apps" AS a1 ON a1."id" = c0."app_id" 
RIGHT OUTER JOIN ((SELECT now()::date - d AS day FROM generate_series (0, 10) d)) AS f2 ON f2."day" = c0."inserted_at"::date 
WHERE (a1."id" = 'ASnYW1-RgCl0I')
GROUP BY f2."day"
```

Comment: Your `WHERE` clause is eliminating the possibility for any `NULL`s from your `apps` table.

Comment: http://wiki.lessthandot.com/index.php/WHERE_conditions_on_a_LEFT_JOIN

Answer (score 3):

Make your where clause part of the join conditions instead. The below code turns the left join on apps to an inner join

```
SELECT f2."day", coalesce(count(c0."id"), 0) 
FROM "conversations" AS c0 
LEFT OUTER JOIN "apps" AS a1 ON a1."id" = c0."app_id" 
RIGHT OUTER JOIN ((SELECT now()::date - d AS day FROM generate_series (0, 10) d)) AS f2 ON f2."day" = c0."inserted_at"::date 
WHERE (a1."id" = 'ASnYW1-RgCl0I')
GROUP BY f2."day"
```

This code does not:

```
SELECT f2."day", coalesce(count(c0."id"), 0) 
FROM "conversations" AS c0 
LEFT OUTER JOIN "apps" AS a1 ON a1."id" = c0."app_id"  and  (a1."id" = 'ASnYW1-RgCl0I')
RIGHT OUTER JOIN ((SELECT now()::date - d AS day FROM generate_series (0, 10) d)) AS f2 ON f2."day" = c0."inserted_at"::date 
GROUP BY f2."day"
```

Comment: You can also `WHERE (coalesce(a1."id",'ASnYW1-RgCl0I') = 'ASnYW1-RgCl0I')`